# TextMate: How do I find the command associated with a keyboard shortcut?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, textmate

I'm pretty sure I remember there being a command in TextMate to tell me which bundle and/or menu item is associated with a particular keyboard shortcut?  Where do I find it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>, then click the magnifying glass, select "Key Equivalent", then type the shortcut.